# Mouse pointer invisible after reinstalling Unity on top of Gnome in Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: unity, 13.10, gnome, mouse, cinnamon

I am using Ubuntu 13.10. I usually use Cinnamon and Gnome shell and had removed Unity and related packages. I re-installed Unity, and everything works fine except that the mouse pointer is no longer visible. It would help if anyone can suggest some ideas to resolve the issue.

I have a Dell XPS 15z L502X with a GeForce GT 540M card. I am also using Gnome shell 3.10.1 and Cinnamon 2.0.12.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Well, I have been able to solve the issue. This seems to be a known problem caused by installing Gnome 3.10. The issue is mentioned here, and the fix is also given.

http://www.webupd8.org/2013/09/how-to-install-gnome-310-in-ubuntu-1310.html

The fix is hard to find on the link, to fix type in a terminal

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. I ran into this problem and could not get it working until I tried your solution.

Comment: Cool, many thanks. Only problem is that I still don't have a cursor in gdm...

Comment: My cursor was invisible after logging in, but only if I didn't move the cursor during the login. If I wiggled the mouse, everything worked fine. This command fixed the problem.