# Where is my Cursor?

Tags: unity, gnome, 13.10, kde, cursor

My os is ubuntu 13.10, I use the following code to remove the kde desktop installed before:

```
  sudo apt-get purge kde*
```

And then use the following code to install gnome 3.10:

```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-next && sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install gnome-shell ubuntu-gnome-desktop
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
  sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

After all these were done, I restart my computer and can not find my cursor in Unity while all things are ok in Gnome. I want to find the  cursor in Unity, what should I do? Any help or suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: This seems to be a known problem of installing GNOME 13.10. Please have a look at this: http://askubuntu.com/a/381832/154414

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, it works for *almost all* people I could find:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.cursor active false
```

**Source:** the bugzilla entry of this bug: [694758](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=694758)

From the bug entry, what I could conclude, this command works because it disables the `cursor` plugin of the `gnome-settings-daemon`. Quoting [Comment 14](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=694758#c14) of the bug:

> (...) looks like mouse pointer plugin is failing to reactivate pointer
>   (anyway, I don't fully understand why the pointer is made hidden when devices
>   like a touchpad are available and no touchscreen one is present)

From [Gentoo's GNOME 3.8 Upgrade Guide's Troubleshooting section](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GNOME/3.8-upgrade-guide#Can.27t_see_the_mouse_pointer_after_login):

> (...) This [command] will prevent the mouse pointer to become invisible and not come back even not running a touchscreen.

Just for a little more knowledge, this is not a GNOME bug, Quoting [Comment 18](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=694758#c18) (from the same bug report):

> There were bugs in the XSync protocol (used to determine which input device was
>   used last) and in the QXL driver that didn't show a cursor in some cases. (...)

Launchpad bug [LP#1238410](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/1238410) confirms it.

Comment: Can you explain why this works?

Comment: @EdenHarder please see the Updated answer. I should have added the explanation and the sources much before as you wanted answer from credible and/or official sources. My fault.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
sudo apt-get install unity-desktop && sudo apt-get install unity
```

then remove what you have installed before by -

```
sudo add-apt-repository--remove ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-next
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo apt-get purge gnome-shell
sudo apt-get purge gnome-documents gnome-contacts epiphany-browser gnome-boxes gnome-shell-extensions gnome-tweak-tool bijiben gnome-clocks
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo reboot
```

hope it helped you.

Comment: Thanks! I have tried this method but not help.